# django: how can I remove the clear and change options from the filefield?

Tags: django-models, django-widget

[image]

How can I remove the clear and change options from the filefield over here? I think I need to modify `class ClearableFileInput(FileInput)` but I am not sure how. I have tried below-

```
class MyClearableFileInput(ClearableFileInput):
    initial_text = ''
    input_text = 'cha'
    clear_checkbox_label = ''
```

to test if it changes the name and it does. I want to remove these fields.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to extend and modify the widget themselves, I found a solution where I could just retrieve and print the values (i.e. the url of the file) in the template.

Do note that {% load static %} is required for {% get_media_prefix %}

```
{% load static %}
<table border='1'>
<tr><th>File</th></tr>
{% for form in formset %}
    <tr>
    {{ form.id }}
    <td><a href={% get_media_prefix %}{{ form.file.value }}>{{ form.file.value }}</a></td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
</table>
```

Comment: Link to the FieldField class API: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.fields.files.FieldFile

Link to the get_media_prefix https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/builtins/#get-media-prefix